# How to find in what directions a function has a derivative?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I have this exercise where I have a bunch of functions (all of them are defined by parts where the function is parted at 0,0) and it asks me to say in which directions these functions have a derivative at (0,0).
I know how to take a derivative in a unit vector's direction by doing a dot product between the gradient vector and the unit vector, but this is somewhat the opposite operation. How should I approach this?

Edit: these are the functions:
[image]

Comment: The way you describe to calculate the directional derivative bia the gradient and etc. is valid **only** if you know your function's differentiable at the given point. So if your function's differentiable the dir. derivative exists in all directions. Otherwise I'm afraid you'll have to go with the definition.

Comment: I understand. But the definition operates based on a generic vector  (lets say vector v= <a,b>). How can I tell in what directions this is valid and when it's not?

Comment: @An It is going to depend on the direction, the function, the point at which the derivative must be taken, etc.

Comment: I have a bunch of different functions parted at (0,0). The point is always (0,0) and the directions are what I'm being asked to find.

Comment: @An I understood that from the very beginning. Then you need the functions! There is no magical formula that can work for **any** function in **any** direction...

Comment: Oh,  I thought there was some general approach, like "take the directional derivative by definition and...". I added the functions to my question.